# Is it possible to trigger from Jquery Validate Framework?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

For validation purpose i am using Jquery validation framework 
I have 3 buttons to perform 3 different actions , could you please tell me how can i call these functions separately from the 
Jquery Validation Framework?

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      "t1": {
        required: true
      },
      "t2": {
        required: true
      },
      "t3": {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "t1": {
        required: "Please, enter t1"
      },
      "t2": {
        required: "Please, enter t2"
      },
      "t3": {
        required: "Please, enter t3"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });

});

$(document).on('click', '#editbtn', function(event ) {
  alert('Edit btn clicked');
});

$(document).on('click', '#savebtn', function(event ) {
  alert('Save btn clicked');
});


$(document).on('click', '#cancelbtn', function(event ) {
  alert('Cancel btn clicked');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label.error {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Start New Category-->
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="custom35auto">
    <div class="portlet box blue">
      <div class="portlet-title">
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-body form" style="display:block;">
        <form id="form" method="post" action="#">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 pull-left"><label class="text-right" style="margin-top:5px">T1</label></div>
            <div class="span9 pull-left"><input type="text" id="t1" name="t1"  class="span12" value="" ></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 pull-left"><label class="text-right" style="margin-top:5px">T2</label></div>
            <div class="span9 pull-left"><input type="text" id="t2" name="t2"  class="span12" value="" ></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 pull-left"><label class="text-right" style="margin-top:5px">T3</label></div>
            <div class="span9 pull-left"><input type="text" id="t3"  name="t3" class="span12" value="" ></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 pull-left"></div>
            <div class="span9 pull-left">

              <button id="editbtn" type="submit">Edit</button>
              <button id="savebtn" type="submit">Save</button>
              <button id="cancelbtn" type="submit">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End New Category-->
</div>
```

and this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/12/

Comment: what different that three buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have three `type="submit"` elements contained *within* the form element and have them operate separately.  The way you have it, the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically trigger a validate/submit from each of them.

You can change one or more of them into `type="button"` elements and then programmatically trigger validation and/or submit as needed.

```
<button id="editbtn" type="button">Edit</button>
<button id="savebtn" type="button">Save</button>
<button id="cancelbtn" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

This will validate *and* submit (similar to `type="submit"`):

```
$('#editbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qq8vn1m7/**

This will validate only:

```
$('#savebtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#form').valid(); // validate form
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/obcnf76e/**

Then you could conditionally check validation and do something:

```
$('#savebtn').on('click', function() {   
    if ($('#form').valid()) {  
        // do other stuff, save form data, etc.
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/svf4m3bm/**